# Linq equivalent to ColumnName = @Param or @Param IS NULL

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to do something with Linq where I may want all the items or I may want a subset of the items. This would be based on a nullable int (int?).

In SQL I would do:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE Column1 = @Param1 OR @Param1 IS NULL
```

Can I do something like that in LINQ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to check whether `@Param1` is null? That’s a check of the input to your query, so you would do that *before* running the query.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you actually mean

```
select col1, col2, col3
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE Column1 = @Param1 OR Column1 = null
```

If so, this is the query
    var result =  from x in MyTable
            where (x.Column1 == null) || (x.Column1 == param1)
            select x;

Or you want to select all when it is null?

Then run different queries

```
if(param1.IsNull())
{
  result =  from x in MyTable
        select x; 
}
else
{
  result =  from x in MyTable
        where x.Column1 == param1
        select x; 
}
```

Yes, I have not added the columns, but the logic is sound.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any c# code so I don't know about your entities but if you're using EF you should get an entity with the name MyTable. Also the following linq query returns an anonymous type which you may want to replace with a class.

Assuming the @Param1 parameter's variable name is Param1 and dbContext is your DataContext object the linq code should look like this.

```
var result = from t in dbContext.MyTable
where Param1 = null or t.Column1 = Param1
select new {
  Column1 = t.Column1,
  Column2 = t.Column2,
  Column3 = t.Column3
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your query in multiple steps:

```
var query = table.Select(x => new {x.Column1, x.Column2, x.Column3});

if (param.HasValue)
    query = query.Where(x => x.Column1 == param.Value);
```